# AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, tkinter, youtube, attributeerror, pytube

when i try to run the program and click the "Download" which is meant to download youtube videos i always get:

```
    AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'get'
```

but i'm not sure why, this is my full code, in case it's useful:

```
import tkinter as tk
import pytube
from tkinter import *
from pytube import YouTube

def handle_focus_in(_):
    e.delete(0, tk.END)
    e.config(fg='black')

def handle_focus_out(_):
    e.delete(0, tk.END)
    e.config(fg='grey')
    e.insert(0, "Input Youtube URL")

def handle_enter(txt):
    print(e.get())
    handle_focus_out('dummy')

def click():
    inp = input.get()
    yt = YouTube(inp)
    print(yt.streams.all())
    stream = yt.streams.first()
    stream.download()

root = tk.Tk()

b1 = Button(root, text="Download", fg="red", command=click)
b1.pack(side=BOTTOM)

e = tk.Entry(root, bg='white', width=30, fg='grey')
e.pack(side=TOP)

e.insert(0, "Input Youtube URL")

e.bind("<FocusIn>", handle_focus_in)
e.bind("<FocusOut>", handle_focus_out)
e.bind("<Return>", handle_enter)

root.title("Ayomide's Youtube Downloader")
root.configure(background="black")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I think the problem is in this line `inp = input.get()`. What do you mean to get in `input`? You haven't declared it. So it uses `input` from python which you don't expect. By the way you'd better use other name for variable not to get such difficult to understand errors.

Comment: I'm not sure, what you meant by `inp = input.get()` but it's actually wrong because with `input.get()` you are referring to the in built `input()` function of python but I think it should be `inp = e.get()` just a guess.

Answer (score 2):

You get this error because the `input` is an built-in function of Python. Let's see: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_input.asp

Furthermore you didn't define the `input` variable.

I have check your implementation and I guess you want to get the `YouTube` link from GUI and pass it to the `YouTube()` class.

You should change the `inp = input.get()` to `inp = e.get()`, in this case the `inp` variable will contain the YouTube URL from GUI.

**I have tested it with the following method:**

```
def click():
    inp = e.get()
    print("YouTube({})".format(inp))
```

**GUI:**

[image: GUI]

**Console output (if I click to the `Download` button):**

```
>>> python3 test.py 
YouTube(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7tN1EoUumHU)
```